# CONCAT() in PostgreSQL with HTML element

Tags: html, postgresql, concatenation

I tried to do some query with an HTML tag inside it like below

```
SELECT  
       "a"."ID_PERMOHONAN", 
       b.NIB AS 'NIB', 
       CONCAT(
            '<b>Nama Kepala</b>:<br> ', a.NAMA_KEPALA,    
            '<br><b>Alamat</b>:<br>', a.ALAMAT_PERWAKILAN, 
            '<br>',
            c.KELURAHAN, 
            ', ', 
            c.KECAMATAN, 
            ', ',  
            c.KAB_KOTA, 
            ', ', 
            c.PROPINSI, 
            '<br><b>Telp / Fax</b>:<br>', 
             a.TELP, ' / ', 
             IFNULL(a.FAX,'-'), 
             '<br><b>Email</b>:<br>', 
              IFNULL(a.EMAIL,'-')
              )  AS 'Kantor Perwakilan', 
              .....
              .....
```

This query is just an half of the actual query, i mention this part only because the error said there are some error in the first CONCAT. I used MySQL and this query works just fine. But when i used this in PostgreSQL, it cant be done. The error just like below.

```
Error Number:

ERROR: syntax error at or near "'NIB'" LINE 1: SELECT "a"."ID_PERMOHONAN", b.NIB AS 'NIB', CONCAT('Nama ... ^
```

I have tried to used double quote (") for all table and alias, but it still same.

Comment: just replace your single quotes for aliases to double quotes: 'NIB' => "NIB"

Comment: Double quotes are for names of tables or fields, single quotes are for string constants.

Comment: how about the aliases like `a.<column_name>` ? should be like this `"a"."<column>"` or `'a'.'<column>'` ? @MaximMarkov

Comment: it should be a."<column_name>" but it is not a good idea to have < and > in field names or aliases